# VS2010 redgate reflector and resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-8.0, .net-reflector

Is it possible to use the Redgate .Net reflector along with ReSharper in Visual Studio 2010? We are using the reflector at the moment and are in the process of finalizing the purchase of the ReSharper but we just want to make sure that the two can work side-by-side, i.e. if we disable the reflector in ReSharper, the Redgate reflector will support navigation to the decompiled source.

Comment: Why would you want to continue to use RedGate .Net Reflector when ReSharper includes dotPeek automatically? Navigation to compiled types happens automagically. Serious... why keep both?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but in order to use it to the full extent, you need to turn off Resharper decompilation if you want to be able to use the Reflector decompilation and debugging support:

[image]